# AbstractApp.__call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'send' connexion 3 and python lambda function aws api gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, connexion

Recently upgraded from connexion version 2 to version 3.
Based on official documents in https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
major change in architecture happend.
my problem:

when using zappa to deploy python lambda function in aws, this general error `Error: Warning! Status check on the deployed lambda failed. A GET request to '/' yielded a 500 response code.` happens. in clouldwatch log review i see also general comment `AbstractApp.__call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'send'`.

Any idea?

Comment: Having same error, did you find a solution?

Comment: Not a solution yet, but just found the cause of error is Zappa and not connexion itself. Zappa seems doesn't support ASGI. do you also utilize zappa?

Comment: please check this blog @MaxLobur https://gilslotd.com/blog/zappa_vs_mangum  "Zappa goes beyond being a shim library to handle WSGI requests........."

Comment: No, I use AWS/aws-wsgi/serverless.com. It also does work on a connexion 2.X, but fails with the same error on 3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connexion 3 migrated from the WSGI to the ASGI interface, which [does not seem to be supported](https://github.com/zappa/Zappa/issues/898) by Zappa.

You can either use an adapter middleware to run Connexion through WSGI ([docs](https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/v3.html#running-the-application)) or switch to a Zappa alternative like [Magnum](https://github.com/jordaneremieff/mangum) which supports ASGI.

Comment: I have not, I am the Connexion maintainer, so my knowledge is mostly on that side.